# Webflux combine results of two downstream calls (and ignore failures)

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I know that my question has been asked already multiple times, but I feel like there is still no satisfying answer to it.

Basically I have two downstream services which I want to call (in parallel) and then I want to combine the results and return it (as Json). Both calls can fail but both results are not mandatory, so also an empty combined response is possible:

```
class FirstResponse {...}
```

```
class SecondResponse {...}
```

```
class CombinedResponse {
   private FirstResponse first;
   private SecondResponse second;
}
```

```
class FirstService {
   Mono<FirstResponse> get(){ 
      return webclient.get(...)
        .bodyToMono(FirstResponse.class)
        .onErrorResume(throwable -> Mono.empty);
   }
}
```

```
class SecondService {
   Mono<SecondResponse> get(){ 
      return webclient.get(...)
        .bodyToMono(SecondResponse.class)
        .onErrorResume(throwable -> Mono.empty);
   }
}
```

```
@RestController(...)
class CombinationController {
   @GetMapping(...)
   Mono<CombinedResponse> getCombined() {
      Mono.zip(firstService.get(), secondService.get(), (first, second) -> {
          return new CombinedResponse(first, second);
      })
   }
}
```

Now in case the calls to firstService fails, also the response from secondService gets ignored. But what I actually would like to have, is that `CombinedResponse` still gets (partially populated).

As a disclaimer I have to say, that I am currently migrating my code from rxjava1 and there in case of downstream errors I just return `Single.just(null)`. This allows me to zip both results and just sets the values to `null`.

Answer (score 1):

About `Mono.zip()` :

> An error or empty completion of any source will cause other sources to
> be cancelled and the resulting Mono to immediately error or complete,
> respectively.

Also, reactor does not allow **null** values, so you should do some workaround in your case. In some simple cases it is easy to define some default value in case of error (for example, empty String), but for custom types it would be weird to create an empty object.

As an alternative for such cases I would suggest to use `Optional`.
This solution adds some boilerplate code, though.

First service:

```java
class FirstService {
   Mono<Optional<FirstResponse>> get(){ 
      return webclient.get(...)
        .bodyToMono(FirstResponse.class)
        .map(Optional::of)
        .onErrorReturn(Optional.empty());
   }
}
```

Second service:

```java
class SecondService {
   Mono<Optional<SecondResponse>> get(){ 
      return webclient.get(...)
        .bodyToMono(SecondResponse.class)
        .map(Optional::of)
        .onErrorReturn(Optional.empty());
   }
}
```

And "combiner" :

```java
@GetMapping(...)
Mono<CombinedResponse> getCombined() {
    Mono.zip(firstService.get(), secondService.get())
            .map(tuple -> {
                // check optionals here from tuple.getT1() and tuple.getT2()
                // and do whatever you want 
            })
            ...
}
```

Comment: I've already seen answers to similar questions that were suggesting to use Optionals. While this would definitely work, I still feel it adds a lot of boilerplate. It feels very weird that there is no better solution to this in webflux.

Comment: @woezelmann I agree with that. As far as I know, this is how Java and Reactor designed, I'm not sure if there is "out-of-the-box" solution for this problem. Hope someone would suggest something better than that.