# Merge Mono and form response even if one of the Mono is empty

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive

How to use two Monos and create an object using data from Monos even if one the mono is empty

Example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Mono<String> firstName = Mono.just("Pavan");
        Mono<String> lastName = Mono.empty();

        Mono<Employee> map = Mono.zip(firstName, lastName)
                .flatMap(t -> Mono.just(Employee.builder()
                        .firstName(t.getT1())
                        .lastName(t.getT2())
                        .build()));

        System.out.println(map.block());

    }

    @Builder
    @ToString
    public static class Employee {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
    }

}
```

I get firstName and lastName as two Mono. It could be that one of the Mono can be empty. I wanted to create Employee object even if one of them is null. Above solution works only if both firstName and lastName are not null.I wanted to create a empty Employee object when both of them are empty

I tried using map like below which also works only when both are not empty

```
Mono<Employee> employeeMono = firstName
        .flatMap(first -> lastName.map(last -> Employee.builder()
                .firstName(first)
                .lastName(last)
                .build()));
```

Comment: You can return Optionals from your methods, see the similar problem and my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75446307/webflux-combine-results-of-two-downstream-calls-and-ignore-failures/75447028#75447028

Comment: according to doc "empty completion of any source will cause other sources to be cancelled". As @kerbermeister mention you would need to wrap String into some object.