How to prevent Mono.zip() from cancelling when one Mono throws an exception?
I'm new to reactive programming in Spring WebFlux. I'm using Mono.zip to combine three Monos, but when one of the Monos throws an exception, the entire zip operation gets cancelled, and I don't get the results from the other Monos.
How can I make sure that even if one of the Monos fails, I still get results from the others? I don't want the entire process to stop if there's an error in one Mono.
Here’s my current code:


Mono<String> mono1 = Mono.just("Result 1");

Mono<String> mono2 = Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Error in mono2"));

Mono<String> mono3 = Mono.just("Result 3");


return Mono.zip(mono1, mono2, mono3)
           .map(tuple -> {

String result1 = tuple.getT1();
String result2 = tuple.getT2();
String result3 = tuple.getT3();
               return result1 + ", " + result2 + ", " + result3;
           });


Thanks in advance!

Does this answer your question: Handling partial failures in case of Mono zip

You can take a look at my answer for the same topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75446307/webflux-combine-results-of-two-downstream-calls-and-ignore-failures/75447028#75447028

to ensure that your Mono.zip operation completes even when one or more Monos throw an exception, you need to handle the errors for each Mono separately. By default, if any of the Monos in Mono.zip fail, the entire operation is cancelled. However, you can use onErrorResume or onErrorReturn to catch the errors and provide fallback values, allowing the Mono.zip to proceed with the other Monos.
Here’s a revised version of your code:
Mono<String> mono1 = Mono.just("Result 1")
                        .onErrorReturn("Fallback for mono1");  // Return a default value on error
Mono<String> mono2 = Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Error in mono2"))
                        .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.just("Fallback for mono2"));  // Provide fallback Mono on error
Mono<String> mono3 = Mono.just("Result 3")
                        .onErrorReturn("Fallback for mono3");  // Return a default value on error

return Mono.zip(mono1, mono2, mono3)
        .map(tuple -> {
            String result1 = tuple.getT1();
            String result2 = tuple.getT2();
            String result3 = tuple.getT3();
            return result1 + ", " + result2 + ", " + result3;
        });

Now, even if mono2 fails, the zip operation will continue, and you will still receive results from mono1 and mono3. Instead of cancelling the entire process, you will get the fallback value for mono2
